# Laravel Feature test: The user is not authenticated Failed asserting that false is true

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8, laravel-testing

I am trying to test the user registration, the test file came with laravel jetstream, I just added some additional fields, and I kept getting this error **The user is not authenticated
Failed asserting that false is true**., please anyone with any idea what's wrong should help. User authentication login is working fine but registrationTest keep spitting this error

```
     • Tests\Feature\RegistrationTest > new users can register
  The user is not authenticated
   Failed asserting that false is true.

      at C:\wamp64\www\fegocomosa\tests\Feature\RegistrationTest.php:71
      67▕             'password'          => 'password',
      68▕             'password_confirmation' => 'password',
      69▕         ]);
      70▕
  ➜  71▕         $this->assertAuthenticated();
      72▕         $response->assertRedirect('/successful');
      73▕     }
      74▕ }
      75▕

    1   C:\wamp64\www\fegocomosa\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:98
     PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
```

**This is the test file**

```
<?PHP

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class RegistrationTest extends TestCase
{
use RefreshDatabase;

public function test_registration_screen_can_be_rendered()
{
    if (! Features::enabled(Features::registration())) {
        return $this->markTestSkipped('Registration support is not enabled.');
    }

    $response = $this->get('/register');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}

public function test_registration_screen_cannot_be_rendered_if_support_is_disabled()
{
    if (Features::enabled(Features::registration())) {
        return $this->markTestSkipped('Registration support is enabled.');
    }

    $response = $this->get('/register');

    $response->assertStatus(404);
}

public function test_new_users_can_register()
{
    if (! Features::enabled(Features::registration())) {
        return $this->markTestSkipped('Registration support is not enabled.');
    }

    $response = $this->post('/register', [
        'username'          => 'Test User',
        'first_name'        => 'User',
        'middle_name'       =>  '',
        'last_name'         => 'Username',
        'date_of_birth'     =>  Carbon::parse('1991-04-12'),
        'about_you'         => 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
         elit. Quaerat, tempora.',
        'profile_photo_path'=> 'profile-photos/image.jpg',
        'gender_id'         =>  1,
        'marital_status_id' =>  1,
        'address'           => 'new adress',
        'phone'             => '0706074000',
        'state_id'          => 8,
        'city_id'           => 162,
        'profession'        => 'Engineer',
        'workplace'         => 'NOUN',
        'jss_class'         => 'Jss1Q',
        'sss_class'         => 'Sss3Q',
        'house_id'          => 2,
        'potrai_image'     => 'mj_1.jpg',
        'entry_year_id'     => 1,
        'graduation_year_id'=> 2,
        'email'             => 'trial@testing.com',
        'password'          => 'password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'password',
    ]);

    $this->assertAuthenticated();
    $response->assertRedirect('/successful');
  }
}
```